# Pinning documents to specific positions in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We have a business requirement for a retail site wherein for **non-search** product listing pages business wants to fix position of certain products.

E.g.
**Url** - /nav/category-id
**Current result** - it displays all the products under that category-id
Say, P1,P3,P5,P7,P2,P4...
**Requirement** - business wants to fix first 3 position with P4,P3,P2...
Rest of the products should maintain their original order.

**What we are doing currently** - we are giving a very high boost in descending order to the required pinned products and it seems to work for now.

**Our concern** - even with very high boost we think we can never garantee the order because of conflicting boost coming from scoring profile.

E.g business might have pinned a new product but our scoring profile is trying to boost products with good sales number.

So what would be the best way to achieve this.

When we tried fixing the position externally by making 2 calls to Cognitive Search, one for getting only pinned products and then making second call to get other products, we just opened a can of bugs with discrepancy coming in facet counts, wrong count on doing pagination and overall the solution became very complex.

Answer (score 0):

Making two calls is a good approach here. One call should responsible for regular results, pagination, refiners, counts, etc. The secondary call should just populate the first N places.

If this complicates your application, you have to change your implementation. From the frontend, you should have the possibility to have individual components that request any number of external services to populate components with content on the page.

The most performant would be to submit both requests in parallel. They should populate content on the page as responses come back. Alternatively, you could make two sequential requests in the backend and then prepare the result by injecting up to three boosted items. We have a similar use case where we present up to three top-selling products above the regular results. When the page loads, two simultaneous requests are submitted to search, and the frontend renders two separate components. You must decide which search response you render your refiners, result counts, and pagination from.

Sure, you could fiddle with boosting rules, but I agree with your concern. It cannot be guaranteed and will probably fail at some point.

Update: With two queries in parallel, your pinned products will be duplicated. I.e. the pinned products will also be part of the main query responsible for presenting results, refiners, and pagination. This ensures correct refiner counts, hit count, filtering, and pagination.

If repeating the pinned items is a concern, you can run two queries in sequence. In the first query, you get up to three pinned items. In the second query, you do not filter out these three items from your query (to ensure the counts are correct). Instead, you skip presenting the pinned items again.

Comment: in our case its not exactly like a separate component. It more like that business wants to pin products at specific positions, but making sure that filter counts are all ok, products dont get duplicated in case of pagination etc is becoming challenging as business keeps increasing the number of products that they want to pin.

Comment: I updated my answer to handle your concern with duplicates and counts. My answer depends on flexibility in both frontend and backend. It sounds like you are looking for an answer that is limited to only manipulating the query or the backend. If you have such constraints, please update the question.